# elastic search get distinct random field values

Tags: elasticsearch

We have elastic search document that has following fields:

```
{
  "stockId": 1
  "sellerId": 100
}
```

Multiple stockId can be mapped to single sellerId but one stock can only be mapped to a single dealer. There are around 10K stocks mapped to 1K sellers. But each sellerId might have different number of stocks i.e. few might have 100 while others have only 1.

**Problem Statement:** We want to select 'N' random documents out of all these documents indexed. The condition is that each of these 'N' document should belong to different seller i.e. distinct "sellerId". (We need to give award to these sellers).

**What I have tried:** I am trying to solve this by elastic query that fetches 'N' random distinct 'sellerId'. (and then elastic query to fetch 1 document of each of these 'N' sellers). One way could be to aggregate on 'sellerId' and then pick random 'N' keys but this is not desirable approach performance wise. Can someone help with better query?

Comment: Do you really need to do this at query time? The golden rule with this kind of data store is to optimise your data for your query - can you expand on the context of your question as this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I agree. I have modified the original problem.

Comment: First instinct - you could maintain a separate list of distinct sellers (maybe another index) and randomly sample that (possibly by searching with a random score). There might be a more straightforward solution though.

Answer (score -1):

I would rebuild my mapping to create a nested document type, with seller being the parent and stockid being the nested object:

```
{
  "sellerid" : {"type" : "integer" },
  "stock_obj" : {
    "type" : "nested",
    "properties" : {
      "stockid" : { "type" : "integer" }
    }
}
```

When you rebuild your index, you would create only one object per seller. Each seller would have all of their stock ids. It seems like there are about 10 stocks per seller, elasticsearch can handle this fine. (If there are thousands of stocks per seller, I would do this differently)

Then, I would do a search for N sellers, [sorted randomly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html), and then as a second sort field, you would sort the stock ids randomly. Not the simplest mapping, but the query is easy and should be fast.

Also, separately, if you're just dealing with ~10k seller/stock data points that are integers, using elasticsearch is probably overkill. It can do what you want, but its main purpose is for searching large amounts of text.

Comment: I wrote less its actually 10L. Could you please share some example to search 'N' sellers randomly and then select stock ids randomly as a second sort field?

Comment: See the example here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html

Comment: I think there's some confusion..the example is to ensure that all documents in a single score level get a similar amount of exposure. For example if there are 100 docs with score 2 documents, they should get similar exposure.. But our case is different.. we want to give same exposure to all sellerid I.e. if we have 5 docs with sellerid 1 and 95 docs with sellerid 2, they should still have equal chances to be chosen

Comment: I see your point. In your case, because there are so few stocks per seller, you can just use random_score to choose a random seller. Then you can randomly pull a stock from each seller.

Comment: No. There's problem in this approach too. If seller 1 has 5 docs and seller 2 has 95 stocks, seller 2 doc will be picked in randomization 19X times. But I want both seller 1 and seller 2 doc to be picked with equal chance

Comment: That won't happen if you set things up the way I suggested. You will be randominzing the sellers first, each seller would have equal likelihood of showing up no matter how many stocks, then you would randomly select one of their stocks.

Comment: you mean by creating new index with just one object for one seller?

Comment: Yes, but internally elasticsearch will use a nested object relationship, so you can also search for the stock ids independently.

Comment: I don't want to reindex..any alternate solution?

Comment: If you don't want to change your index, you can do an aggregation like you mention in the comments. Not sure what perf. issues you ran into, aggregating on 1K sellers is tiny, should not be a problem for ES even on an under-powered machine.